# FullCalendar - How to allow droppable on specific day in calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar

I have a FullCalendar embedded in my webpage, and there will be an external event to be drag and drop on the calendar, but should only be allow to drop on Saturday of current month. droppable:true enable droppable on entire calendar. How can I enable drop only for Saturday in current month?

**If Saturday is clicked and highlighted (yellow), it shoud not be droppable as well

Css:

```
  .blink{
    animation: blinker 2s linear infinite;
    background-color: red !important;

}

@keyframes blinker {  


     50% { opacity: 0; }

   }


body {
    margin: 40px 10px;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}

#datepicker {
    max-width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}


    #wrap {
        width: 1500px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      #external-events {
        float: left;
        width: 150px;
        padding: 0 10px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        background: #eee;
        text-align: left;
      }

      #external-events h4 {
        font-size: 16px;
        margin-top: 0;
        padding-top: 1em;
      }

      #external-events .fc-event {
        margin: 10px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      #external-events p {
        margin: 1.5em 0;
        font-size: 11px;
        color: #666;
      }

      #external-events p input {
        margin: 0;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }
```

Javascript:

```
 var holidays=[];
    var saturdays=[];
    var calEventStatus = [];
    $(document).ready(function(){



        // Manage status of dragging event and calendar



            /* Required functions */

            var isEventOverDiv = function(x, y) {

                var external_events = $( '#external-events' );
                var offset = external_events.offset();
                offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
                offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

                // Compare
                if (x >= offset.left
                    && y >= offset.top
                    && x <= offset.right
                    && y <= offset .bottom) { return true; }
                return false;

            }


            function makeEventsDraggable () { 

                $('.fc-draggable').each(function() {

                    // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                    $(this).data('event', {
                        title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                        stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                    });

                    // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                    $(this).draggable({
                        zIndex: 999,
                        revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                        revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                    });


                    // Dirty fix to remove highlighted blue background
                    $("td").removeClass("fc-highlight");

                });

            }

            /* initialize the external events
            -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

            $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

                // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                $(this).data('event', {
                    title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                    stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                });

                // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                $(this).draggable({
                    zIndex: 999,
                    revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                    revertDuration: 0,  //  original position after the drag
                            stop: function( event, ui ) {

                                 dragStop();

                            }
                });

            });



      $('#datepicker').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
                },
                editable: true,
                droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar
                dragRevertDuration: 0,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                drop: function(date, jsEvent, ui) {
                    // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                    if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                        // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                        $(this).remove();
                    }

                    // if event dropped from another calendar, remove from that calendar
                    if (typeof calEventStatus['calendar'] != 'undefined') {
                        $(calEventStatus['calendar']).fullCalendar('removeEvents', calEventStatus['event_id']);
                        //$(calEventStatus['calendar']).fullCalendar('unselect');
                    }

                    //makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventReceive: function( event ) { 
                    //makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventDrop: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 


                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventDragStart: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {


                    // Add dragging event in global var 
                    calEventStatus['calendar'] = '#datepicker';
                    calEventStatus['event_id'] = event._id;



                            drag();

                },
                eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) { 

                    if(isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
                        $('#datepicker').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                        var el = $( "<div class='fc-event'>" ).appendTo( '#external-events-listing' ).text( event.title );
                        el.draggable({
                          zIndex: 999,
                          revert: true, 
                          revertDuration: 0 
                        });
                        el.data('event', { title: event.title, id :event.id, stick: true });
                    }

                            dragStop();

                    calEventStatus = []; // Empty
                    //makeEventsDraggable();
                },
                eventResize: function( event, delta, revertFunc, jsEvent, ui, view ) {
                    makeEventsDraggable();
                },

                        dayClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                         var date = new Date($('#datepicker').fullCalendar('getDate').format());

                         var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
                         var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(),date.getMonth()+ 1, 0);



                         var formattedFirst= new Date(formatDate(firstDay));
                         var formattedLast= new Date(formatDate(lastDay));
                         var formattedSelect= new Date(calEvent.format());


                         if (formattedSelect>=formattedFirst && formattedSelect<= formattedLast){
                             if($(this).css('background-color')=="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"){ //rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
                                $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');
                                holidays.push(calEvent.format());


                             }
                             else{
                                 $(this).css('background-color','rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' );

                                  var index= holidays.indexOf(calEvent.format());
                                  if (index > -1) {
                                        holidays.splice(index, 1);
                                  }
                             }
                         }



                   },
                   viewRender: function(view, element) {
                          makeEventsDraggable();
                          holidays=[];
                          saturdays=[];

                            var d = new Date($('#datepicker').fullCalendar('getDate').format());

                            var getTot = daysInMonth(d.getMonth()+1,d.getFullYear()); //Get total days in a month


                            for(var i=1;i<=getTot;i++){    //looping through days in month
                                var newDate = new Date(d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth(),i)

                                if(newDate.getDay()==6){   //if Saturday
                                    saturdays.push(formatDate(newDate));
                                }

                            }

                            function daysInMonth(month,year) {
                                return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
                            }

                   }



            });



    });

   function formatDate(date) {
        var d = new Date(date),
            month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
            day = '' + d.getDate(),
            year = d.getFullYear();

        if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
        if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

        return [year, month, day].join('-');
   }

   $("#nextBtn").on('click',function(){
        var holidayStr= holidays.join();



       var date = $("#datepicker").fullCalendar('getDate');


       console.log(date.year());


        $("#addedHoliday").val(holidayStr);
         $("#scheduleMonth").val(""+(date.month()+1));
          $("#scheduleYear").val(""+date.year());

   });



function drag() {



if(saturdays){
    for(var i=0;i<saturdays.length;i++){    //looping through days in month
        if(holidays.indexOf(saturdays[i])<0)
          $('.fc-day[data-date="'+saturdays[i]+'"]').addClass('blink');



      }


    }
   }
function dragStop(ev){

    if(saturdays){
        for(var i=0;i<saturdays.length;i++){    //looping through days in month
            if(holidays.indexOf(saturdays[i])<0)
              $('.fc-day[data-date="'+saturdays[i]+'"]').removeClass('blink');

        }
    }
}
```

Html:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
<div id='wrap' class="form-group">

                <div id='external-events'>
                  <div id='external-events-listing'>
                    <h4>Draggable Events (Saturday)</h4>
                            <div class='fc-event' ondrag="drag()" ondragend="dragStop(event)" >My Event 1</div>

                  </div>

     </div>
 </div>
```